# Limit properties proof

Tags: real-analysis

I am going through chapter three of Rudin's principle of analysis and I'm having trouble following the proof of the following property from Rudin $(3.3d)$:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/s_{n} = 1/s$ where $\{s_{n}\}$ is a complex sequence that converges to $s$.

**Pf**

Choosing $m$ such that $|s_{n} - s| < \frac{1}{2}|s|$ if $n \geq m$, we see that $$|s_{n}| > \frac{1}{2}|s|\ \ \ (n \geq m).$$  Given $\varepsilon > 0$,  there is an integer $N > m$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $$|s_{n} - s| < \frac{1}{2}|s|^{2}\varepsilon.$$  Thus, for $n \geq N$, $$\left|\frac{1}{s_{n}} - \frac{1}{s}\right| = \left| \frac{s_{n}-s}{s_{n}s}\right| < \frac{2}{|s|^{2}}|s_{n}-s| < \varepsilon$$
I'm not sure if its the phrasing, but I find this hard to follow.  I'm confused as to what $m$ is here, starting from the first statement.  Then I am also unsure as to why if $n \geq m$, we get the statement afterwords.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $s_n\to s$, given any tolerance (I avoid using the term $\epsilon$ here to avoid confusion below), in this case $\frac{1}{2}|s|$, we can find $m$ such that whenever $n\ge m$, then $s_n$ is within $\frac{1}{2}|s|$ of $s$. That is the definition of $m$. Then for $n\ge m$, since $s_n$ lies within the open ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}|s|$ of $s$, it must have magnitude strictly greater than $\frac{1}{2}|s|$. That is the second statement you asked about. The final sequence of inequalities arises as follows:
$$\left|\frac{s_n-s}{s_ns}\right| = \frac{|s_n-s|}{|s_ns|}.$$
But $|s_n-s|<\frac{1}{2}|s|^2\epsilon$ and $|s_ns| > \frac{1}{2}|s|^2$ (from the first inequality), so we get
$$\frac{|s_n-s|}{|s_ns|} < \frac{|s_n-s|}{|s|^2/2} = \frac{2}{|s|^2}|s_n-s|
      < \frac{2}{|s|^2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}|s|^2\epsilon = \epsilon.$$